# Send Whatsapp image to specific contact in ios

Tags: ios

How to send image to specific contact on whatsapp through my application on iOS?

Android provide Intent to share image to specific contact like:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
File f=new File("path to the file");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.whatsapp","com.whatsapp.ContactPicker"));
sendIntent.setType("image");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
sendIntent.putExtra("jid", PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators("919xxxxxxxxx")+"@s.whatsapp.net");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"sample text you want to send along with the image");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apple's default method UIActivityViewController to share image

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

NSArray *arrImg = @[img];

UIActivityViewController *activity = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] 
initWithActivityItems:arrImg applicationActivities:nil];


[self presentViewController:activity animated:YES completion:nil]
```

Comment: how it's posible to share image on whatsapp??

Comment: this will open default share activity controller, if whatsapp installed on your device it will show whatsapp icon on list, from that list you can select whatsapp and share image on it.

Comment: but it's not share image direct to specific contact

Comment: my question is to open specific/one contact chat screen and send image direct